# how to create slider in view pager in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to implement view pager in Android.But i want to create layout something like this [image]

I m trying but left side and right side half image is not showing with current page .Can someone help how to work with this.Thanks to appreciate.

Comment: Tushar :- Thanks . How can i vote up you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In older to do that you will have to create your own custom ViewPager or you can use one of the libraries present out there. I would recommend using [MultiViewPager](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager) which is easy to use and is also lightweight.

In order to use this library, download it and add it in your project and then simply add the following View in your Layout:

```
<com.pixplicity.multiviewpager.MultiViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:matchChildWidth="@+id/child_view_to_match" />
```

**NOTE**: Be sure to declare the app namespace:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

This is the end result:

[image: example]

Hope it helps! :)